# How would Rand's relationship with these characters be classified?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

In *aMoL*, Rand has a conversation with Gawyn where he states that he's is Galad's half-brother. But he then goes on to state that he is *not* related to Elayne (presumably by Andoran standards). Nevertheless, by *our* standards, how is he related to her? A half-half-brother? Would their relationship be legally permissible, say, in the U.S.?

Also, Luc would be his uncle. Is Moiraine his half-aunt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rand's and Galad's mother is Tigraine Mantear who was the daughter-heir of Andor and married to Galad's father Taringail Damodred.

When she disappeared into the Waste after birthing Galad, Taringail then married Morgase Trakand (Elayne's mother) who later became the Andoran queen. Morgase and Taringail had Elayne and Gawyn while they were married.

Meanwhile in the Aiel waste, Tigraine became pregnant with Rand via clan chief, Janduin of the Taardad Aiel.

So there is no direct blood connection between Elayne and Rand as their parents were not in any way related by blood (probably there are a number of distant links over the generations between house Trakand and Mantear but there's nothing concrete in Jordan's writing that I have found, but royal houses usually have numerous connections to other royal houses over a number of generations).

This means that Rand and Elayne's relationship would be legal in the USA and probably anywhere.

As Taringail is not connected to Rand by blood this means that Moiraine (Taringail's half sister) is not related to him. Meanwhile Luc (Tigraine's brother) is Rand's uncle.

[image: Rand's family tree]

Answer (score 1):

Rand and Elayne are blood related, they are third cousins, as they share a common great grandmother,though i don't know her name, Ishara Casalain, is infact the first queen and a much more distant relation to them both. meaning both Rand's and Elayne's mothers are cousins and each child is a second cousin to each other's mother, thus third cousins with one another. As for Luc, he is Rand's uncle. As for Moiraine, she is not related to Rand though she is Rand's brother Galadedrid's Aunt as she is his father's sister.